Prove this rising factorial identity : $\frac{(x + 2n)!}{x! (2n)!} = g(x^2 + (2n+1) x)$ for polynomial $g$.
I found this :
$$f_2(x) = (1 + x)(1 + \frac{x}{2}) =(x+1)(x+2)/2!$$
$$f_4(x) = (1 + x)\left(1 + \frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{4}\right) =(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)/4! $$
$$f_6(x) = (1 + x)\left(1 + \frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3})(1 + \frac{x}{4}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{5}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{6}\right) =(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)/6! $$
$$f_8(x) = (1 + x)\left(1 + \frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{4}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{5}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{6}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{7}\right)\left(1 + \frac{x}{8}\right) = (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)(x+7)(x+8)/8! $$
and in general :
$$f_{2n}(x) = \frac{(x + 2n)!}{x! (2n)!}$$
So related is the gamma function.
We have the following pattern for integer $n > 0$ :
$$f_{2n}(x) = g(x^2 + (2n+1) x)$$
where $g$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients of degree $n$.
Examples :
$$f_8(x) = \frac{(x^2 + 9x)^4}{8!} + \frac{(x^2 + 9x)^3}{672} + \frac{109}{3360} (x^2 + 9x)^2 + \frac{761}{2520} (x^2 + 9x) + 1$$
$$f_6(x) =  \frac{(x^2 + 7x)^3}{6!} + \frac{7}{180}(x^2 + 7x)^2 + \frac{7}{20} (x^2 + 7x) + 1$$
$$f_4(x) =  \frac{(x^2 + 5x)^2}{4!} + \frac{5}{12} (x^2 + 5x) + 1$$
Prove it.
see the source :
https://sites.google.com/site/tommy1729/polynomial-problem
I find this surprising ! How and why are these polynomials a polynomial of another polynomial in the first place ?
Is this related to some gamma function symmetry ? Or to stirling numbers ?
How does one even notice such a thing ?
It does not seem obvious from induction or so.
Maybe mod arithmetic is involved ?
I did not find this result on the wiki of rising factorials.

Please know that $1 + n/x$ is ambiguous.  Do you mean $(1+n)/x$ or $1 + (n/x)$?  Please edit your post using parentheses to disambiguate.

It is not ambiguous. Division has higher priority than addition.

The "pattern" does not "break down for $n=1$": $f_2(x)=\frac12(x^2+3x)+1$.

I edited. Thanks for the feedback

Consider $(x+2n)(x + 2n - 1)(x+2n-2)...(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)$. Multiplying the first and the last and so on, we get:
$(x^2 + (2n+1)x + 2n)(x^2 + (2n+1)x + 4n-2)\cdots$. Replacing $x^2 + (2n+1)x$ by $t$ we can see a polynomial in $t$ as desired.

@sku nice ! Can you describe the polynomial $t$ ? I suggest writing an answer.

Letting $y:=x+n+\frac12$,
$$\begin{align}f_{2n}(x)&=\frac1{(2n)!}(y-n+1/2)(y-n+3/2)\dots(y+n-3/2)(y+n-1/2)\\&=\frac1{(2n)!}
(y^2-(n-1/2)^2)(y^2-(n-3/2)^2)\dots(y^2-(1/2)^2)\\&=:g(x^2+(2n+1)x)\end{align}$$
since $y^2=x^2+(2n+1)x
+c$ where $c:=(n+1/2)^2$.
More explicitely:
$$\begin{align}g(t)&=\frac1{(2n)!}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left(t+c-(k+1/2)^2\right)\\
&=\frac1{(2n)!}(t+n^2+n)(t+n^2+n-2)\dots(t+4n-2)(t+2n).\end{align}$$

You should add that we multiplied the first and last to get that form imo.

Easy imo, hence left to the reader for brevity.
